# gtrendsR error HTTP 410

Tags: r, windows-10, google-trends

I am new to use a package, gtrendsR, running in R 3.4.1, windows 10.
I succeeded in gconnect, but i get the following error message for any types of query passing to gtrends like below.

```
library(gtrendsR)
gconnect(usr=my_user_name,psw=my_password)
google.trends = gtrends(c("NHL"), geo="US",start_date="2017-01-01")

Error: Not enough search volume. Please change your search terms.
In addition: Warning message:
In request_GET(x, url, ...) : Gone (HTTP 410).
```

Anybody has some ideas to solve the problems?

Comment: According to [the Github page](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR), the package version on CRAN is not working. They suggest installation from Github. Also note that `start_date` is no longer an option in the newer version.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant but the vignette states: 'Due to recent changes to Google Trends API, the CRAN version of the package is no longer working. If you wan to continue to query Google Trends, you have to install the development version of the package. This will be soon deployed on CRAN.' https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just in case, I reinstalled gtrendsR 2.0. from zip file from CRAN. Then somehow gconnect was not found... Maybe I need to wait for the new version.

Comment: `gconnect` does not exist in newer versions, there is no requirement for Google authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Finally I made it. Really appreciated.